# Node.js + Node-Webkit + Node-SerialPort Based Application - Is this Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-webkit, node-serialport

I am new to Node.js and before I go head first into taking on a new technology and migrating my c# based application, I wanted to make sure what I had in mind is possible with Node.js and if it is recommended.

*So please let me know your opinion!*

My application has the following requirements:-

1. TCP server (to receive packets from TCP clients such as smart phones, computers etc.)
2. Serial port access (To control a hardware device)
3. Web server facilities (to serve HTML5 pages or provide web services intefaces)
4. Simple native app like GUI for configuration.
5. All of this needs to be packaged nicely for end users to install simply.

Why I would want to do this you may ask?? The reason I am most interested in using Node.js is due to the cross platform nature, including the ability to install on cheap single board/embedded computers.

This is my thinking:-

**Node.js**  - to provide the TCP server, serve HTML5 pages and provide web services interfaces.

**[Node-Webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)** - to provide the simple native app like configuration interface. I also believe that it provides the ability to package my application for simple distribution, but I am not sure? (I could leave out Node-Webkit if there was another way to package my app for simple distribution. Although it is preferred as even having to find the IP Address of the computer so as to access a web browser interface would be tricky for some of my users.)

**[Node-SerialPort](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport)** - to provide the ability to communicate with the hardware device. The instructions will come from 1 of three sources. 1) TCP connection  2) HTML5 Webpage Initiated  3) Web Services Initiated.

Comment: Did you get success for this? I am trying to achieve same? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That's what most people use Node.js for
2. https://npmjs.org/search?q=serial+port
3. Again, that's what most people use Node.js for
4. Because of 1 and 3, the most obvious UI for node.js apps is the browser. Write a config page to control your app. Using node-webkit is overkill, just use whatever browser is already available. Node can run multiple listeners on multiple ports, serving the same app.
5. `npm install` is pretty simple.

Go learn how to write simple Node.js apps (with express for easy http servering, and jade or nunjucks for easy html templating) and then move up from there.

Comment: Thanks Mike, very much appreciated! With point 5, you say that npm install is pretty easy. Are you talking about the command line installation like you do with the Node Packaged Modules (NPM)? The product I am building needs to be distributed to end users, not developers, so it needs to be packaged in a .exe or .msi for Windows, a .dmg for Macintosh. So any command line installation is out of the picture. Can you package node.js applications for simple distribution for the average user?

Comment: I stopped counting the number of apps that say "you need to have X installed". That could be an MSVC++ redistributable, or in this case nodejs. Packing it up as an OS-specific installer is a bit weird when the power of nodejs is that it's universally executable scripts, but you could just pack your project as an "installer" that's just a self-extracting archive with a post-extract script that runs npm install to fetch all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

**Point 5**. I understand the fact of having an installer. I would suggest that the .msi or .exe will create a Windows Service for NodeJs. Then the node js server will launch at Windows startup and the end user will access the browser with

```
http://localhost:< a port number>/.
```

**Packaging NodeJS** : To package nodejs, you can copy the nodejs.exe from the installation directory of nodejs into the directory where you developp the node application. Then zip everything. You unzip it on another computer and it will execute.